# No gnome-control-center 19.04

Tags: 19.04

have no gnome-control-center followed the instructions friend gave me and got this printout.

```
(gnome-control-center:21023):GLib-GIO ERROR**:20:08:51.135:Settings Scheme'com-system76.hidpi' is not not installed Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

WHAT DOES THIS MEAN AND WHAT AM I TO DO?

Comment: Are you running Pop!_OS Linux?

Answer (score 3):

I found a workaround, I installed:

```
sudo apt-get install hidpi-daemon
```

(https://github.com/pop-os/hidpi-daemon/)

Maybe was the latest update of gnome-control-center.

Comment: thanks it worked but what happens the next time they try to adjust somthing? I really appreciate your help thanks again

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are referencing a Pop!_OS set of routines - if so, that question is about Pop!_OS and not Ubuntu, despite being based upon Ubuntu.

Try looking into the launchpad respository for Pop!_OS at the System76 team site:

https://launchpad.net/%7Esystem76/+archive/ubuntu/pop/+packages

The package `hidpi-daemon` in their PPAs provide the required daemon.