# Ubuntu 19.10 Network Settings Not Working

Tags: 19.10, gnome-control-center

I upgraded laptop from Ubuntu 19.04 to 19.10 via do-release-upgrade and network-manager no longer works. I have tried this `gsettings set org.gnome.ControlCenter last-panel ''` but with no luck

Comment: What do you mean no longer work ? Can you elaborate on this.

Comment: I have managed to solve it with https://askubuntu.com/a/1138148/973625